# Hadoop reducer error: "Shuffle Error: Exceeded the abort failure limit; bailing-out"

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I've got a hadoop 0.20 map/reduce job that used to run just fine. In the last few days, it's getting stuck in the reduce phase at 16.66%, and I'm seeing the following error when I look at the reduce task in the jobtracker;

```
Shuffle Error: Exceeded the abort failure limit; bailing-out.
```

Can anyone tell me what that means, and maybe point me in the right direction so I can figure out how to fix this?

Comment: Is there anymore information in the reduce task logs for the failed attempts?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a separate log for the reduce task - it's all in 'syslog' files in /var/hadoopdata/mapreduce/userlogs/job_[whatever] But, looking in there, I can see some errors where it's trying to contact the other node using a host name which doesn't resolve. I'm not sure why that would result in the error I'm getting, but it's wrong so I'll try fixing it and seeing if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error corresponds to the maximum number of times a reducer tries to fetch a map output before it reports it and maps to the property `mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.maxfetchfailures`.

You could try increasing this property, but the default value of 10 is usually enough, so there may be something more serious.

I remember a case where something similar with fetch failures was due to an incorrect **/etc/hosts** file and after googling a bit it looks like this could be the issue, so try the following:

- use hostnames instead of ips
- synchronize your /etc/hosts across all nodes (easier if you use something like Puppet)
- try commenting out “127.0.0.1 localhost”
- restart the cluster

Comment: Thanks. There was a missing entry in /etc/hosts, and a problem with iptables, either of which would prevent the reducer from fetching results from the mappers. Adding the hosts entry and flushing iptables seems to have fixed the problem.